# ¿Cómo crear un AlertDialog que se abra una sola vez?

Tags: android, alertdialog

Tengo una función básica de un `AlertDialog`que es la que verán a continuación:

```
public AlertDialog guiarapida() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Bienvenido/a")
            .setMessage("Te seguiremos que pases por nuestra guía rápida ")
            .setPositiveButton("No volver a preguntar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Ir a guía rápida",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

El asunto es que deseo que este `AlertDialog` se muestre cuando el usuario haya entrado al menú de inicio por primera vez y al hacer click por ejemplo en ***"no volver a preguntar"*** no se muestre la próxima vez que inicie la app. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Es posible almacenarlo en una base de datos? Si no, puedes agregar una variable booleana en un fichero en el dispositivo del usuario y que justo antes de mostrar el mensaje se compruebe si ese fichero existe. De esta manera podrás manejar si mostrar el mensaje o no con una condición.

Comment: no, tengo una tabla para el dialogo, pero creo que la segunda opción que mencionas en mas efectiva por que al borrar los datos de la app lo podrá ver nuevamente ...

Comment: Sí, así es porque el fichero se eliminará con la app a la que va asociada.

Comment: esto seria usando SharedPreferences ?

Comment: Yo la verdad que nunca he usado SharedPreferences. Yo lo que suelo hacer es crear un fichero como en Java y almacenar ahí la información. Sin embargo, no sé si es la manera más correcta de todas.

Answer (score 3):

Te hago una propuesta usando `ShredPreferences`, lo que hace a continuación es asignarle un valor a un entero, es decir, si ya lo ha marcado le da un valor de 1, de lo contrario le da un valor de 0. Ese entero lo guarda en las preferencias y dependiendo el valor guardado se va a mostrar el diálogo:

**EDICIÓN**

Antes que todo, tienes que revisar si existe el valor ya guardado:

```
private int valorGuardado; // Creas tu variable global en espera de los valores


SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("check_value", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

valorGuardado= sp.getInt("check_value_key",0);
if (valorGuardado== 0) {
    abrirDialogo();
} else {
   //No muestra el diálogo
}
```

Ya en tus botones de `setPositivebutton` y `setNegativeButton` le asignas el valor correspondiente al entero y mandas a llamar el método que guarda las preferencias:

```
...

.setPositiveButton("No volver a preguntar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                         valorGuardado= 1;
                         guardarPreferencias();

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Ir a guía rápida",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         valorGuardado= 0;
                         guardarPreferencias();

                        }
                    });

...
```

Método `guardarPreferencias();` donde contendrá los necesario para guardar los valores:

```
private void guardarPreferencias(){
    SharedPreferences guardar_cheked_alerta = getSharedPreferences("check_value", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = guardar_cheked_alerta.edit();
                    editor.putInt("check_value_key", valorGuardado);
                    editor.commit();
}
```

PD: No lo he probado, pero puede funcionar o darte alguna idea de como realizarlo, si deseas ver más acerca del tema puedes visitar [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Gracias, me has dado una idea, pero este Dialogo en tu ejemplo esta compuesto por checkbox, aunque se podria realizar casi de la misma namera con setPositiveButton y setNegativeButton

Comment: ¡Oh! Leí mal xD Creí que tu diálogo tendría el típico checkbox. Mi código funciona exactamente igual que sin _check_, lo único que cambiarías es en quitar el if que revisa si esta marcado y  lo de `valorCheck=1` se lo pasas al `PositiveButton`y el `valorcheck=0` al `Negativebutton`, puedes crear un método que contenga el guardado de datos, ejemplo: _GuardarPreferencias();_ y eso lo mandas a llamar en ambos botones, justo después de asignarle valor al entero. :D

Comment: así es, gracias !

Comment: No hay de que @FelixBeeb,  ya edité mi respuesta.

Comment: no funciona, buscare el error ...

Comment: Qué error te muestra

Comment: no muestra un error, pero no cumple su función

Comment: ¿Puedes entrar a esta sala  y seguir el tema ahí?http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50893/problema-con-dialogalert