# Como hacer para poner las notas de lanzamiento||Actualizacion de tu app en Android Studio?(aporte)

Tags: java, android-studio

Se que se usa SharedPreferences y AlertDialog pero la verdad que no lo se bien.

Comment: Gracias por la contribución, te sugiero agregar más detalles a la pregunta , revisa [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Después de una búsqueda veloz...Estas son mis citas:

[¿Cómo mostrar una Activity específica solo en la primera ejecución de la Aplicación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43150/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-una-activity-espec%C3%ADfica-solo-en-la-primera-ejecuci%C3%B3n-de-la-aplicac)

[¿Cómo crear un AlertDialog que se abra una sola vez?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41379/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-alertdialog-que-se-abra-una-sola-vez/41399)

Bueno no es tan difícil cuando captas la idea

Al iniciar la app que se tiene que mostrar una ventana emergente(AlertDialog) la cual muestre algunos datos de tu app(actualización, que permisos requiere,etc) y por medio de 2 botones uno que no volver a mostrar y el otro que rechaza leer||canselar||ir a otro Activity

Cada botón al presionarlo deberá de guardar un valor:

no volver a mostrar=1

echaza leer||canselar||ir a otro Activity=0
Aqui el codigo

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int respuesta;//declaramos una variable global

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("check_value", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);//declaramos sharpreferences

    respuesta= sp.getInt("check_value_key",0);//asignamos el valor a la variable global

    //creamos una condicion para saber si el valor ya habia sido guardado
    if (respuesta== 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Bienvenido")
                .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Notas de la nueva version " +
                        "<br> Nuevas Actualizaciones:" +
                        "<br> -*****************" +
                        "<br> -*****************" +
                        "<br> -*****************" +
                        "<br> -*****************" +
                        "<br> Recomendaciones: " +
                        "<br> -*****************" +
                        "<br> -*****************" +
                        "<br> -etc..."))
                .setPositiveButton("no volver a mostrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        respuesta= 1;
                        saveRespuesta();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("leer||canselar||ir a otro Activity", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        respuesta= 0;
                        saveRespuesta();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    }else{
    //sino no hace nada 
    }
}
private void saveRespuesta(){//guargamos el valor de respuesta
SharedPreferences guardar_cheked_alerta = getSharedPreferences("check_value", Login.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = guardar_cheked_alerta.edit();
editor.putInt("check_value_key", valorGuardado);
editor.apply();
}
}
```

bueno es lo que yo coloque a mi aplicaron y funciona a la perfecciona doy las gracias a las personas que ayudaron a poder completar mi problema!